# How to get started with Ukrainian alphabet?

Tags: resource-request, ukrainian

I want to learn Ukrainian, but I need a tool to learn the Ukrainian alphabet before I get started with Duolingo's Ukrainian course.

Comment: Welcome to Language Learners.SE! What makes you think you need to learn the alphabet in the first place, in favor of e.g. listening/speaking some basic phrases? Also, the Wikipedia page for [Ukrainian language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_alphabet) contains some basic info on Cyrillic alphabet and pronunciation of its letters.

Comment: Hi, could you clarify what you mean by "tool"? Would a normal text-based resource or a video also be fine? And what language should it be in? Only in English?

Answer (score 2):

Anki(droid) is a flashcard program, which has user-created decks. There seem to be decks for Ukrainian alphabet: https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/Ukrainian (one general, one for vovels, one for consonants). I have not used them.

I have used Anki decks to more-or-less learn Japanese hirakana and katakana to the extent that I can pronounce words written in them. I stopped studying the language further, but when I did also study it via Duolingo, the initial exercises with kana were terribly easy. I guess it should work for Ukrainian, too.